# How would I look for specific text across the whole page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I have recently gotten into website automation. I wanted to test it out by filling out some of my attendance google forms. Since not all attendance forms are made the same, how would I look for a specific text like "Name" or "Email address" across the whole form? Here is an example div from one of the google forms:
[Form photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzGGk.png)

`<div class="freebirdFormviewerViewItemsItemItemTitle exportItemTitle freebirdCustomFont" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i.desc.1498692874 i9">Name: <span class="freebirdFormviewerViewItemsItemRequiredAsterisk" aria-label="Required question">*</span></div>`

How would I look across the whole form for the "Name: " that you see in the div?

I could go form by form and `driver.find_element_by_xpath` for each but I would like to keep everything condensed and have this script be almost universal. I have a screenshot of part of the google form if it helps. Would love to hear your suggestions!

Comment: Have you considered using BeatifulSoup?
Check this out: soup.find_all(string="Name")
[soup.find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

Comment: This worked very well thank you so much!